# how to call async function inside then() block along with finally() in MongoDB Driver?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, async-await

I am learning MongoDB in Node.js. I have a `main` function which returns the `collection` object pointing to the desired collection.

```
main()
    .then((collection) => {
        findDocs(collection)
    })
    .catch(console.error);
    .finally(() => client.close());
```

I am calling `findDocs` function by passing the `collection` object. But this fails with
`PoolClosedError [MongoPoolClosedError]: Attempted to check out a connection from closed connection pool` error. But if I remove `finally()` block, it works fine but the database connection doesn't close, as anyone would expect.

Is there a way around this problem or suggestions for calling the callback `async` function better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must use async-await to solve your problem:

here an example

```
main()
    .then(async (collection) => {
        await findDocs(collection)
    })
    .catch(console.error);
    .finally(() => client.close());
```

or instead of using then/catch closure use the try-catch closure in the function that calls the main function:

Example:

```
async function index(){
  try{
   const collection = await main();
   const docs = await  findDocs(collection)

  }catch(e){
    console.error(e)
  }finally{
    client.close()
  }

}
```

Another option is closing the client when findDocs end:

```
main()
  .then((collection) => {
    findDocs(collection)
      .catch(console.error)
      .finally(() => client.close());
  })
  .catch(console.error);
```